# PHP - Generating Titles and descriptions without parent part (technical SEO)

Tags: php, seo, title

could someone help me with this technical SEO problem. At our website we have product pages whose title, description (and keyword) tags are generated by further given PHP code (function). Now the problem is that we don't want parent category titles and descriptions to appear (added) in same elements of product page (titles, descriptions). Currently, parent items appear at the beginning of every products page title and description in this way:

*Product page title tag:* **parent category title tag** - current product name

*Product description tag:* **parent description tag** - "about_short" the current product

I believe that PHP function that generates that is:

```
function get_seo() {
global $ln, $get_seo, $SEO, $f, $site_post;
function get_field($text, $field) {
    global $t_texts, $ln, $idp;
    $temp_idp=$idp;
    if (is_numeric($text)) {
        $r=$t_texts->select("id='$text' AND state<>'seo'");
        $f=mysql_fetch_array($r);
        //print_r($f);
        if (is_numeric($f[$field]))$text=$f[$field];
        else $text=ln($f[$field]);
        // parent add ///////////
        $add="";
        if($f["idp"]!=0) $add=ln($f["name"]);
        if ($add) {
            if(ln($f[$field]))
                $add="";
            $text .= $add;
        }
        $temp_idp=$f["idp"];
    }
    $text=trim(strip_tags(str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $text)));
    if ($field!="title") $text=str_replace("\"", "", $text);
    //if $text is not empty return $text;
    if (strlen($text)>2) return $text;
        else { return ($temp_idp) ? get_field($temp_idp, $field): false; }
}

$arr = explode(" ", "title description keywords");
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    $mas = $arr[$i];
    if (ln($f[$mas]))
         $SEO[$mas] = ln($f[$mas]);
    else {
        if ($temp=get_field($get_seo[$mas], $mas)) $temp=", $temp";
        $SEO[$mas] = ln($f["name"]).$temp;
    }
}
if (!$t_texts) $t_texts = new mysql("texts$site_post");
if (($f["module_id"]==855)&&(intval($_GET['id'])>0)) {
    $r = $t_texts->query("SELECT * FROM `projects` where id='".(int)$_GET['id']."' limit 1");
    $f2 = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $SEO['title']  .= (ln($f2['name']))?' - '.htmlspecialchars(ln($f2['name'])):'';
    $SEO['description']  .= (ln($f2['about_short']))?' - '.htmlspecialchars(ln($f2['about_short'])):'';
}
```

}

What I need is :

*Product page title tag:* Current product name

*Product page description:* "about_short" the current product

And category titles and descriptions to stay the same, but just appear in those category pages (not in product).

I've tried to be as clear as I could, but if You have any further questions about the coding or something related, I'd be glad to provide it.

And thanks, guys for your help!